# Failure prediction from sensor data using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, time-series, prediction

I am going to do a research project which involves predicting imminent failure of an engine using time data obtained from sensors. The data basically contains the readings of various embedded sensors every 10 minutes for many months. Such data is available for about 100 or so different units (all are the same engine model), along with the time of failure.

While I do have a reasonably good understanding of Machine Learning, I am at a loss of approaching this. I have done a few projects that involved static datasets (using SVMs, Neural Nets, Logistic Regression etc.) and even one on predicting time series. But this is quite different. While the project involves time data, it is hardly a matter of predicting the future values. Rather it is a case of anomaly detection on sequential time data.

Please could you give some ideas as to how I could approach it?
I'm particularly interested in Neural Networks/ Deep Learning, so any ideas on using them for this task would also be welcome. I would prefer to use Python or R, although I would be open to using something else if it was particularly geared for this sort of task.
Also could you give me some formal terms using which I could search for relevant literature?

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought: How about using a neural network to classify a set of sensor data at time *t* as to whether or not the engine will fail before time *t + d* for some (predetermined) time interval *d*?

Comment: @beaker Yes that would be perfect, but how do I approach even this problem? Like what neural nets to use? How do I make the neural network learn different sensor data streams and then indicate there is a very high chance of failure in the next hour or so? Do you know any papers or articles or tutorials that address such a problem?
The main issue I'm having is that I'm unable to classify what kind of problem it is. It certainly isn't a static anomaly problem nor is it a time series prediction problem. Thanks

Comment: @user3046045 did you find a solution for your problem. Please share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general comment, try hard to express everything that you know about the physical system in a model, then use that model for inference. I worked on such problems in my dissertation: [Unified Prediction and Diagnosis in Engineering Systems by means of Distributed Belief Networks](http://riso.sourceforge.net/docs/dodier-dissertation.pdf) (see chapter 6). I can say more if you provide additional details about your problem domain.

Don't expect general machine learning models (neural networks, SVM, etc) to figure out the structure of the problem for you. Having the right form of the model is much, much more important than having a general model + lots of data -- this is the summary of my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link. I will certainly go through it. I didn't quite get your point about "Having the right form of the model".

Comment: Regarding the project,I have one large excel sheet for each engine unit. One such sheet contains time data for different sensor readings (like temperature, voltage levels etc.). So there are 100 such excel sheets. Also, another master sheet that contains at what times the engines failed (for whatever reason). The goal is to use the data and build a real time monitoring system that can give an advance warning of a failure within the next hour or so

Comment: @user3046045 Re: "Having the right form of the model": what I mean is a model based on what you know about how the engine works. Don't treat the problem as `output = F(input1, input2, input3, ...)` where `F` is a black box.

Comment: @user3046045 After thinking about it for a few minutes. A couple of ideas: construct a time-to-failure model (also known as a reliability model or survival model) in which time to failure is a function of temperature, voltage, etc. The idea is that at normal temperature, etc., time to failure is longer, and as temperature increases, time to failure gets shorter. Also, I am guessing there are different failure modes (axle breaks, insulation fire, etc). Build one time-to-failure model for each mode and then look at the minimum of the waiting times. This is a so-called competing effect model.

Comment: Regarding the model, is it really important to get into the intricacies of the engine? I mean if I am using neural networks, won't it model the engine failure model on its own by learning the training data? Frankly, I don't know that much about engines, I'm doing this as a data science project.

Comment: I'm somewhat aware of TTF models, but from what I know they are more on the statistical and operations research side. I was hoping to do it using Machine Learning techniques. I know that these 2 things aren't mutually-exclusive but I want the algorithm to learn from the data rather than me doing statistical analysis to predict TTF. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @user3046045 Failures are rare and therefore you probably have much, much more non-failure data than failure. So you have to squeeze as much as you can out of those precious failure data. It is not necessary to completely model engine physics -- it is a matter of degree: to the extent that you can build domain information into the model, the more mileage you can get out of the available data, and the more directly interpretable your models and their outputs will be. Just to say that you are going to build a competing effects time-to-failure model is already a big step in the right direction.

Comment: @user3046045 Try to build as much structure as possible into your overall model and then identify parts for which you do not have any prior information. For those parts, build a neural network model. You may well have several black box models, each handling a different part of the overall model. Bear in mind that black box models will probably give unphysical outputs when inputs are outside of the range of the training data, as will very often be the case. You want a model which will extrapolate as well as possible to previously-unseen inputs, and that requires making use of prior information.

Comment: Ok but I'm not sure how to "label" something as failure data or OK-working data. All I have are like 50 sensor streams, 5 min resolution for 5 years. And in that 5 year period at some point in time (or maybe 2-3 points in time) that unit has failed. I have data for like 100 such units. Where can I go from here? Do I have to do feature extraction? Can I directly feed this raw data into some learning algorithm that is suited for time sequences, like RNNs?

Comment: Hey @user3046045, what did you end up using to solve this?

Comment: @RenierBotha I used basic thresholding, looked for sudden changes in mean and variance. But that was back then. Today I work with more advanced ML techniques. What's your particular problem? Maybe I can suggest something.

Comment: Hi @user3046045. I have a similar problem using sensor data for failure prediction. My objective is to find the factors necessary to prevent before failure occurs. I have used RF, XGB and CoxPH with minimal success. Could you share the names of some of the advanced ML techniques that are available for these kind of problems?